# arguments with pure command line

Tags: bash

I don't know if this is possible with terminal command line rather than a script. I want to type a command which takes variables $0, $1 and enter the variables separately either at the start/end of the same line or on terminal prompt

ie

```
$ cd /var/$0/$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, just using [variables](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html). For instance:

```
$ varA="directory_name"
$ varB="file_name"
$ cd "/var/$varA/$varB"
```

You may also want to put this in one line:

```
$ varA="directory_name"; varB="file_name"; cd "/var/$varA/$varB"
```

Comment: Excellent, I will accept when the timer runs out. Just out of curiosity, how long does bash remember the variable - just for the session? And how can I properly wipe a variable - varA = "" ?

Comment: The variable should remain available as long as your `bash` process is running. You can also make the variable accessible inside scripts and other instances by using `export` before the declaration (`export varA=...`). To unset a variable, you can use [either `varA=""` or `unset -v varA`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262696/using-unset-vs-setting-a-variable-to-empty).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using explicit variables, you can also use positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`...):

```
$ set 'some dir' 'some sub-dir'
$ cd "/var/$1/$2"
```

(note that contrary to `zsh`, with `bash`, it's important to remember to use the double quotes around the variables).